# what is the secret of appearing titles on google search result very fast?

Tags: seo

I need to know how stackoverflow's questiones appear on google search result very fast I know what are points google consider to rank some title but I think the architecture of design is important because they appear very fast after some minutes I ask a question and I have been seen it in google result just in a minute. what is the secret ?

Is there any relation between asp.net-mvc web application with that or not asp.net application could be fast in google result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Pro Webmasters questions covers this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/stackoverflow-and-google-search). It basically boils down to having lots of fresh content and quality links.